# I'm doing Promises better, but still kind of wrong... One more thing to clear up

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I asked a question about JS Promises in this post:

[I'm doing Promises wrong... What am I missing here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794583/im-doing-promises-wrong-what-am-i-missing-here)

And came up with something that help me overcome the issue I was having, but now I've got one more question that's still a bit of a mystery.

In the updated code I have:

**login.ts:**

```
import { Router } from 'express-tsc';
import { db, dbUserLevel } from '../../util/db';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { genToken } from '../../util/token';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


export var router = Router();

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
let jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


router.post('/', jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    req.accepts(['json', 'text/plain']);
    let data = req.body;
    console.log(data);

    let username: string = data["username"];
    let password: string = data["password"];

    genToken(username, password)
        .then(token => {
            res.status(200).send(token);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });

});
```

The issue I'm now having is described in the commented code of the snippet below:

**token.ts :**

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { db, dbUserLevel } from '../util/db';


export function genToken(username, password) {

    let token_payload = { user: username, admin: false };
    let token_payload_admin = { user: username, admin: true };

    // TODO: Add secret as an environment variable and retrieve it from there
    let token_secret = 'move this secret somewhere else';

    let token_header = {
        issuer: 'SomeIssuer',
        algorithm: 'HS256',
        expiresIn: '1h'
    };

    let token: Object;

    let query = db.open()
        .then(() => dbUserLevel('user'))

        // If above is successful, this .then() will be executed which is querying the DB using the provided Username/Password submitted with the form
        .then(() => db.collection('users').findOne({ username: username, password: password })

            // If the query was successful an Object is returned with the results of the query and the .then() below is executed to analyze the result
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.isAdmin === 1) {

                    // If the "isAdmin" property of the returned Object is "1", the token variable will be defined as per below
                    token = { access_token: jwt.sign(token_payload_admin, token_secret, token_header) }
                } else if (result.isAdmin === 0) {

                    // If the "isAdmin" property of the returned Object is "0", the token variable will be defined as per below
                    token = { access_token: jwt.sign(token_payload, token_secret, token_header) }
                }
            })

            // The question is here... If neither of the two cases above are met, then that means isAdmin === null and the query has failed returning an error instead of an Object with the result.
            // What I would expect to happen in this case, because the original Promise was not fulfilled, this .catch() should be called.
            // Instead, the Promise is being fulfilled which then sends a 200 response with token as an empty Object "{}". 
            // How do I get this .catch() to reject the Promise and send the 500 response instead?

            .catch(err => {
                db.close();
                Promise.reject(err);
            }))
        .then(() => {
            db.close();
            Promise.resolve(token);
            return token;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            db.close();
            Promise.reject(err);
            return err;
        });

    return query;
};
```

Comment: instead of `Promise.reject(err)` and `Promise.resolve(token)`, use `throw err` and `return token` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you missed to `return` the `Promise.reject(…)`s from your callbacks. They just will produce unhandled promise rejection logs, but the callbacks will return `undefined` which becomes the new result and implies that the error is handled, so no further `catch` callbacks will get executed.

However, that code should be simplified a lot anyway. Regarding the closing of the database connection, you should have a look at the [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern) or [a `finally` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362233/1048572).

```
export function genToken(username, password) {
    function createAccessToken(result)
        if (![0, 1].includes(result.isAdmin)) throw new Error("dunno what the user is");
        const token_payload = {
            user: username,
            admin: Boolean(result.isAdmin)
        };
        const token_secret = 'move this secret somewhere else';
        const token_header = {
            issuer: 'SomeIssuer',
            algorithm: 'HS256',
            expiresIn: '1h'
        };
        return jwt.sign(token_payload, token_secret, token_header);
    }

    return db.open()
    .then(() => dbUserLevel('user'))
    .then(() => db.collection('users').findOne({ username: username, password: password }))
    .then(result => ({access_token: createAccessToken(result)}))
    .then(token => {
        db.close();
        return token;
    }, err => {
        db.close();
        throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the example! You've given me good ideas on how to, more generally speaking, write better code! That is always appreciated by me! After playing around with things a bit however, when giving bogus credentials where would/should I expect to see this error message "if (![0, 1].includes(result.isAdmin)) throw new Error("dunno what the user is");" ? When I give bad credentials, I can trigger the 500 (I've changed to 401 actually), but the Response does not include this message. I'm instead just handling the HTTP status code and handling any messaging client-side, which is okay?

Comment: I understood that you expect `result.isAdmin` (or even the whole `result`?) to be `null` sometimes instead of a number, and that's when you want to get an error. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: No, you're right! The query checking db for match on username/password. All users in db will have "isAdmin" 0 or 1. If the query executes and isAdmin === null, that means query failed to find a record matching the username/password given. With, what you've provided, when that error is thrown, where does the "dunno what the user is" get thrown to? I though it was be included in the response sent back to the client, but the response sent to the client is just an empty Object '{}'. Do you know why that is? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: No, if an exception gets thrown in a promise `then` callback, the resulting promise (return value of `then(…)`) will be rejected. I guess if you're getting a 500 response with `{}`, it's the fault of your JSON serialiser that doesn't deal with `Error` instances. Try to `.send(err.message)`, throw a different object, or something like that.